# Is there a way to avoid widows when placing an image at the end of a paragraph?

Tags: css

I have a site where the client wants to be able to put a stylized graphic at the end of some link text. Conceptually, it'd be like this:

`<a href="#">This is My Fancy Title<img src="fancypic.png"/></a>`

Except at some widths, word-wrapping causes the image to wrap as a widow on it's own line.

I've tried quite a few different approaches to this, including the `widows` CSS property, but nothing seems to work 100%.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ideally it would wrap on the previous word. The `widows` property would have been perfect if it worked with the image.

Comment: I could have worded the original request better -- basically they just don't want the image, itself, hanging around by itself on it's own line. A single word + image as a widow would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You can use `white-space: nowrap`.

That will cause the text and image to not wrap to the next line.</s>

Add a span and put one or 2 words and the image in it, make it `inline-block`

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is My Fancy <span>Title<img src="fancypic.png"/></span></a>
```

Comment: Aye, that was one of the things I tried. The link then overflows off the screen when the window is narrow, unfortunately. If I had a way to wrap the last couple words and the img element inside a `span` with that property, I'd probably be pretty happy.

Comment: You can put them in a span, make sure it is `inline-block`, and it will work.